# Что делать,если в коде предложение на русском,а когда я запускаю программу,то какие-то символы

Tags: c++

Я написал код,где есть русское предложение.Английский текст читается,а русский загораживается какими-то символами.Что делать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread95729.html

Comment: Ответ легко гуглится. Вы могли найти это по первой ссылке.

Comment: Кодировочку utf-8 использовали...